# Semaphore for pausing actions, not limiting concurrent actions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I have a method that's called constantly by many threads that looks up data in a data structure.

When that data structure needs to be updated, I need to block all threads attempting the lookup until the update is complete.

I could use a semaphore with X permits, and have the update method acquire all X permits before executing the update then releasing them again - but now X also serves the secondary purpose of limiting my lookup method to X simultaneous calls, which I don't want.

What other options do I have for blocking calls to the update method without limiting simultaneous executions of it?

Comment: This is probably contrary to your current train of thought, but limiting the number of simultaneous calls to your method may not necessarily be a bad thing. Your machine will have practical limits on how many threads can run anyway due to available memory and the sheer amount of time it takes to spawn new ones - perhaps you could set X to some large number you're sure to never reach (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`), or a number that will likely cause processing efficiency issues before it is reached (`10*Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`). It all depends on what that method call is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into using a  ReadWriteLock, specifically [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).  Each reading thread can lock on the `readLock` and when a write needs to happen just lock on the `writeLock`.

The write lock, when held, will block all reads (and subsequent writes) from occurring until the write lock is released.  Threads that hold `readLock` can be executed simultaneously. That is, many threads can hold the readLock at the same time.

If you are using Java 8 I would suggest [StampedLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html)

Comment: We're still on 7, but ReentrantReadWriteLock looks like *exactly* what I need, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

John Vint's answer—reader/writer lock—sounds like the best fit to your problem, but you made me think of an ancient, and very simple design pattern called a "turnstile".

(WARNING!  This is a non-answer: The turnstile does not actually solve the problem.  It could prevent a thread from *entering* the lookup routine, but it does nothing about a thread that already is *in* the lookup routine when the updater thread becomes active.)

Anyway, turnstile dates back to a time when a semaphore was considered to be *the* low-level primitive from which all other synchronization objects would be derived.  (Way older than Java).  There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but I've always loved the simplicity of the implementation:

```
class Turnstile {
    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    // To be called in threads that need to "pass through" the turnstile.
    public void passThrough() {
        semaphore.acquire();
        semaphore.release();
    }

    // To be called only in the single thread that owns the turnstile.
    public void lock() {
        semaphore.acquire();
    }

    // To be called only in the single thread that owns the turnstile.
    public void unlock() {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: John's answer should be more performant; but it's cool to see an implementation with a clever use of the basic semaphore - thanks :-)

Comment: Although, having stopped to think about this, it wouldn't actually have solved the problem.  A thread 'Y' that has passed through the turnstile is now executing the lookup method.  Before it completes, there's nothing to stop thread 'X' from calling "lock()" and beginning to make changes to the datastructure.

It prevents  *new* threads from beginning the unsafe code whilst an update is in progress, but doesn't contemplate threads that may already be there.

Comment: @tdimmig, yes, that is why I said that John Vint's answer was the "better fit".  I will amend my answer to say something a little stronger.